# does vimeo api support live streaming from camera?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio-api, live-streaming, vimeo-api

I like to know if vimeo-api provides live streaming by accessing the camera and giving a live url to be accessed by peoples who want to watch. I know a little about twilio api which can be used for my scenario but not sure about viemo-api. I want to do this in nodejs and currently doing with twilio api.

Thank you for reading.